# Return null in response

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

This is my code, I don't know what's wrong with it. It is just a simple login.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private login login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://services.hanselandpetal.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        login = retrofit.create(login.class);

        Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_log_out);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                login.isLogin("eslam@yahoo.com","123").enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            String MyResult = response.body().string();
                            Log.d("sample",MyResult);
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Interface

```
public interface login {

    @GET("api/register")
    Call<ResponseBody> isLogin(@Query("Email") String Email,@Query("Password") String Password);

}
```

Comment: We don't know what's wrong with it either. What errors are you getting? What is happening when you run it? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: the app is crashing and say in logcat

Comment: say in logcat that
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference

Comment: sorry my first time to use stack over flow :D

Comment: Can you add raw response?

Comment: sorry what you mean by adding raw response

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the NullPointerException your `response.body()` is null.

To find out what exactly the problem is, you should log your network traffic by adding an interceptor to your Retrofit configuration.

To do so add `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'` to your app dependencies, sync with gradle and then change your Retrofit code to this:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(); 

// set your desired log level
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); 

// add logging as last interceptor
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
   .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
   .client(httpClient.build())
   .build();
```

After this, you should see your network request/repsonses in the android log. This should help to figure out why your response body is null.